# Printing the sum-size of copied files in bash

Tags: bash

I would like from the code below to print the sum-size of the files being copied instead of the size of each copied file separately.

```
#!/bin/bash
input_folder=/a/b/c
output_folder=/d/e/f

cd $input_folder

for i in *.tiff; do
  size=$(wc -c < ${i})    
  cp -v ${i} $out | sleep 1 | echo -ne "$size%\033[0K\r"
done
```

This `bash` prints every second the size of the file being copied.

For example, in second `1` it copies `file A` and prints the size of `file A`. In second `2` it copies `file B` and prints the size of `file B` instead of the total size of files `A+B`. In second `3` it copies the `file C` and prints the size of `file C` instead of the total size of files `A+B+C`

How can I do it in `bash` specifically?

Comment: You should note that it doesn't print the size every second, it sleeps one second between echo file. If it takes long enough that you want to display some progress, you probably don't want an extra delay.

Comment: @ RalfFriedl. Thanks! probably just sleep `0.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just sum up the single sizes and `echo` it afterwards.

```
#!/bin/bash
input_folder=/a/b/c
output_folder=/d/e/f

cd $input_folder

size_sum=0    
for i in *.tiff; do
  size=$(wc -c < ${i})    
  size_sum=$((size_sum + size))
  cp -v ${i} $out | sleep 1 
done

echo ${size_sum}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
size=$(wc -c < ${i})
```

This isn't a very smart way to get the size of a file. Running `wc` like that will involve *reading* the whole file, which really is completely unnecessary since all you want is the size which the filesystem already knows and can tell you.

This is mitigated by the fact that you copy the file afterwards, and so need to read it in any case. A moderately-sized file will probably stay in the cache for the duration, so the reads don't actually hit the disk. But still, it would seem sensible to just read the size.

With GNU utilities, you can get the size of the file with `stat -c %s "$filename"`. Sadly, the options `stat` takes are different on other systems, and I don't think there's a better, more portable way (apart from running Perl)

```
cp -v ${i} $out | sleep 1 | echo -ne "$size%\033[0K\r"
```

Here, the pipeline seems odd. `cp` doesn't produce any output (to standard output), at least not without `-i`, so there's nothing to pipe. Even if it did, `sleep` doesn't read anything so any output from `cp` would be wasted. The same thing happens between `sleep` and `echo`. This is basically the total opposite of what pipelines are usually used for, but it does have the effect that all the commands run in parallel, and the shell waits for all of them to complete, so that pipeline takes at least one second to run, regardless of how fast the copy would otherwise be.

If you want to sum the file sizes, the shell's arithmetic expansion `$(( .. ))` is what you probably want. So, without any extra sleeps:

```
dest=/path/to/destination
total=0
for file in *.tiff; do
    size=$(stat -c %s "$file");
    printf "current %d total %d\n" "$size" "$((total += size))"
    cp -- "$file" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To save on the arithmetic in your script, you can just take the size of the concatenation of the files:

```
cat *.tiff | wc
```

The UN*X kernel will conspire with you to make this just as efficient as taking the sizes of the files separately.

Comment: I think this should be `wc -c`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sum with `+=` if the variable is declared as integer:

```
$ declare -i size
$ size+=100; echo "$size"
100
$ size+=200; echo "$size"
300
```

Your script (with variable expansions correctly quoted):

```
#!/bin/bash
input_folder=./a/b/c
output_folder=./d/e/f
declare -i size

for i in "$input_folder"/*; do
  size+=$(wc -c < "${i}")    
  cp -v "${i}" "$output_folder" | sleep 1 | echo -ne "$size\033[0K\r"
done
```